# Как сделать счетчик нажатий в telegram bot api?

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

Всем привет.

Есть работающий простой бот, который что-то куда-то отправляет.
Захотелось прикрутить к постам кнопки Like\DisLike. Нечто подобное выглядит вот так: https://prnt.sc/qeqdco

Посему вопросы такие:

- Должно быть только один инкремент от одного пользователя, если он уже лайкал и нажимает второй раз, то срабатывает декремент. Как то нужно фильтровать или запоминать пользователя. Как?
- Как перехватить нажатие кнопки? У меня в возвращаемом массиве вообще нет поля callback_query. Хотя все мануалы ссылаются на работу с этим полем.

Ну и сам бот выглядит вот так:

```
$token_tg = "to:ken"; // Токен Телеграма
$chat_id = "-1001300id";
$message = 'В мире снаружи есть бесчисленное количество возможностей, и каждая из них — начало большой истории.';

/**
... в этой части подготавливаем картинку $res[$random]['name'] ...
*/

$keyboard = array(
    "inline_keyboard" => array(array(
                            array("text" => "LIKE", "callback_data" => "Like"),
                            array("text" => "DISLIKE", "callback_data" => "DisLike")))
);
$keyboard = json_encode($keyboard, true);

$ch = curl_init("https://api.telegram.org/bot$token_tg/sendPhoto?chat_id=$chat_id&photo=http://website.com/1TG/{$res[$random]['name']}&caption=$message&reply_markup=$keyboard");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Может есть какое-то уже готовое решение по установке лайк\дизлайк к сообщениям бота?

Answer (score 0):

В базе данных делаете таблицу, где сохраняете идентификатор записи, под которой лайк\дислайк и id пользователя. Потом проверяете есть такая запись или нет. Если есть, добавляете и ставите +1, если нет, удаляете и ставите -1